# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android-studio

I am creating an android application where the user enters data to search and then application sends it to server and then server sends search result back to the client. I am getting this error.

```html
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$dbname = "android_api";
$con=mysql_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "SELECT d.unique_id, u.name FROM downloads d LEFT JOIN users u ON u.name = d.unique_id WHERE d.link = 'www.google.com'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $json['users'][]=$row;
 }
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname);
$unique_id = $_POST['unique_id'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$sent = $_POST['sent'];
$Sql_Query = "insert into downloads (unique_id,link,sent) values ('$unique_id','$link','$sent')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){

 echo 'Data Inserted Successfully';

}
else{

 echo 'Try Again';

}
mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: Can you get data from this script via web-browser?

Comment: yes. The main problem is while passing the value from HttpPost to PHP.
I am not able to pass the edittext values properly but if use query through web browser it works.

Comment: So, you get correct json with browser and broken json with your app, don't you?

Comment: Yes. I dont know to fix the issue. I have been stuck on this for sometime

Comment: So, looks like problem is with your app, not with your PHP. Just try to create staic json-file and get it by your app to be sure.

Comment: Can you take a look at my code and help me with this?

Comment: Your php looks ok, but I can't help you with java. I recommend you insert your problem java code into question and somebody could help you with it.

Comment: Thanks mate. In that sql statement is it right to check a variable with the data stored in the database i.e d.link = {'$variable_name'}; Is this the appropriate way?

Comment: The error only comes when I assign a variable in it. if i give in a constant value such as d.link='www.google.com'; It works fine

Comment: Test this `... d.link='".$variable_name."'`. Don't forget escape vars of your sql-query in production/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a String value to an array reference.

```
 $json['users'][]=$row;
```

Try to asign it to a element of the array instead

```
$json['users'][0]=$row;
```

If it works, assign this number dynamically.

Comment: I tried it. Its not working. Can you tell me how can I pass an EditText value to a php variable?